# Validation Rule Lead Category required based on Lead Source selection

Tags: picklist, validation-rule

I have Lead Source as a picklist with these options (Distribution Partner, Personal Referral, Event/Trade Show, TBP Event, Website, Other)

I have created a custom text field called Lead Category. I want to require Users to complete the Lead Category field when the Lead Source of (Distribution Partner, Event/Trade Show, TBP Event or Other) is selected as the Lead Source.

Example:
Lead Source = Distribution Partner or Event/Trade Show or TBP Event or Other > then require User to complete the custom text field Lead Source.

I tried some variations of this but no success!

```
ISPICKVAL(Lead Source, "Distribution Partner" || "Event/Trade Show" || "TBP Event" || "Other")
```

require text field of Lead Category to be manually filled with text.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ISPICKVAL` in the way you've tried, it can only check one value at a time. This is covered in the [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISPICKVAL).

> `ISPICKVAL(picklist_field, text_literal)` and replace picklist_field with the merge field name for the picklist; replace *text_literal* with the picklist value in quotes. *text_literal* cannot be a merge field or the result of a function.

You need to call `ISPICKVAL` multiple times and OR the results of those together instead.

```
ISPICKVAL(Lead Source, "Distribution Partner")
|| ISPICKVAL(Lead Source, "Event/Trade Show")
|| ISPICKVAL(Lead Source, "TBP Event")
|| ISPICKVAL(Lead Source, "Other")
```

You'll then want to check if your Lead Category is blank, so your final validation rule will look something like this.

```
ISBLANK(LeadCategory__c)
&&
(
    ISPICKVAL(Lead Source, "Distribution Partner")
    || ISPICKVAL(Lead Source, "Event/Trade Show")
    || ISPICKVAL(Lead Source, "TBP Event")
    || ISPICKVAL(Lead Source, "Other")
)
```

Comment: Alex thank you. I had some minor modifications but this worked great                                                                          ISBLANK(Lead_Category__c)
&&
(
    ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, "Distribution Partner")
    || ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, "Event/Trade Show")
    || ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, "TBP Event")
    || ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, "Other")
)

Comment: ISBLANK(Lead_Category__c)
&&
(
    ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, "Distribution Partner")
    || ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, "Event/Trade Show")
    || ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, "TBP Event")
    || ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, "Other")
)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well,

OR(Text(Lead Source)=='Distribution Partner',Text(Lead Source)=='Event/Trade Show',Text(Lead Source)=='TBP Event',Text(Lead Source)=='Other') && ISBLANK(Lead Category)

Thanks,
Raviteja